# Can't kill socket after "binding to socket error"

Tags: linux, sockets

When trying to connect to a socket, it tells me the address is already in use.
I try to kill the corresponding process but I get the message that this operation
is not permitted...

```
Error binding to socket myapp.sock: Address already in use
ERROR: Failed to start myapp daemon.
make: *** [run-sim] Error 1
[grabher@myapp ex1]$ ps -C myapp
PID TTY          TIME CMD
2075 ?        00:06:43 myapp
[grabher@myapp ex1]$ kill -9 2075
2075: Operation not permitted
```

Anyone an idea how I could do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of trying to kill other processes that you didn't start, have you considered running your own process on a different port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to kill the process as root

for example in ubuntu would be `sudo kill -9 pid`

Comment: No way that I can get root access, is there another way? Hard reboot hopefully also helps :P

Comment: You also need to stop using `kill -9`, because that doesn't give processes a chance to clear up after themselves.

Answer (score 0):

If the process is owned by root then there is no way you can kill the process (non root user need to have permission to kill root owned or other user owned processes), ask admin to change the permissions of the process.